# How to get uploaded absolute s3 image path in Django

Tags: python, django

How to get uploaded s3 image absolute path. I tried `model_instance.image.file.path` but it throws an error `django backend doesn't support absolute paths`

I have multiple models with image (FileField) and wanted to get absolute path of it to be served to FE. Locally things won't get messed up but when I deploy it on production couldn't get absolute path.
I was thinking to define a method `get_image_path()` in each model and concatenate related path something like f"https://{domain}/{static_location}/{self.image.file.url}"

Please suggest if this is an ideal way to do this or is there any better approach.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AWS isn't going to give you the absolute path to a file on their servers. They don't want you seeing what their root directory structure looks like.

I think what you are looking for is the url of the image?

```py
model_instance.image.file.url
```

This will give you a url like

```
https://bucket.s3.region.amazonaws.com/path/of/image.jpg
```

Assuming you're using `boto3` and `django-storages`